# Typescript is throwing an error with crypto generateKeyPair 'rsa'

Tags: node.js, typescript, cryptojs

I have a function where I am attempting to generate public and private PEM key strings where I will use the private to generate a signed JWT token and store the public key in a database.

The NodeJS version is working in several production apps, but when adding this to one of the typescript projects, we are getting a mystery error.

```js
// javascript version
const newCrypto = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      crypto.generateKeyPair('rsa', {
        modulusLength: 1024,
        publicKeyEncoding: {
          type: 'spki',
          format: 'pem'
        },
        privateKeyEncoding: {
          type: 'pkcs8',
          format: 'pem'
        }
      }, (err, publicKey, privateKey) => {
        if (err) throw err
        resolve({ publicKey, privateKey })
      })
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err)
    }
  })
}
```

```js
// typescript version
const newCrypto = async (): Promise<any> => {
  crypto.generateKeyPair('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 1024,
    publicKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'spki',
      format: 'pem'
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs8',
      format: 'pem'
    }
  }, (err: Error, publicKey: string, privateKey: string) => {
    if (err) throw err
    return { publicKey, privateKey }
  })
}
```

This is the following error that I am getting from Typescript. After spending some time googling, I found nothing online regarding this issue. Anyone have any ideas?

```sh
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"rsa"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"x448"'.

8   crypto.generateKeyPair('rsa', {
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking through the crypto.d.ts file, I saw that the callback function could potentially return null in place of the error.

Below is the type definition:

```js
function generateKeyPair(
        type: 'rsa',
        options: RSAKeyPairOptions<'pem', 'pem'>,
        callback: (err: Error | null, publicKey: string, privateKey: string) => void,
    ): void;
```

Solution:

```js
const newCrypto = async (): Promise<any> => {
  crypto.generateKeyPair('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 1024,
    publicKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'spki',
      format: 'pem'
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs8',
      format: 'pem'
    }
  }, (err: Error | null, publicKey: string, privateKey: string) => {
    if (err) throw err
    return { publicKey, privateKey }
  })
}
```

By adding a null callback error type, the error was resolved.